# Ansible : delete all files and directories inside a folder and not the folder itself

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

i'm trying to run a task which deletes all the content of my project fiolder , without deleting the folder itself:

**my folder** : appFolder **----contains---->** file1 , file2 ... fileN , directory1 ...directoryN

i ve tried to use **ls** , **fileGlob** , but that didn't work properly.

```
- name: delete old version files
  file:
   path: "{{ paths }}"
   state: absent
  with_filesglob:
   - "{{paths}}deletes/*"
```

also with shell module (not good because it didn't delete file with special characters names)

```
- shell: ls -1 /some/dir
  register: contents

- file: path=/some/dir/{{ item }} state=absent
  with_items: {{ contents.stdout_lines }}
```

**A better solution ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until [#18910](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/18910) is fixed (`state=empty` for dirs), we are stuck with workarounds.

Here's one of them:

```
- name: Clean build folder
  shell: cd /project/build && find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf --
```